# mysqli VALUE portion not taking input from html form

Tags: php, html, sql, mysqli

How do I store the user input into the Insert VALUES of the two html form values?
In the last line of the script VALUES doesn't store these from form

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
require 'connectit.php';
mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO bills (bill_name, bill_cost)
VALUES ($_POST['bill_name'], $_POST['bill_cost'])";
?>

// html form
<form action="updatebill.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="bill_name" placeholder="Bill name"><br>
  <input type="text" name="bill_cost" placeholder="Bill cost"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: try to print $_POST['bill_name'] and $_POST['bill_cost']. Also you are using mysqli all wrong. Please go read guides of how to use mysqli

Comment: Wrong because I used it in the query function?

Comment: NEVER use `$_POST` directly in your queries.

Comment: One reason this won't work is because your form method is not set to POST, but GET instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "demo");

// Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// Escape user inputs for security
$bill_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['bill_name']);
$bill_cost = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['bill_cost']);


// attempt insert query execution
$sql = "INSERT INTO bills (bill_name,bill_cost) VALUES ('$bill_name', '$bill_cost ')";
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    echo "Records added successfully.";
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}

// close connection
mysqli_close($link);
```

Comment: ERROR: Could not able to execute INSERT INTO bills bill_name,bill_cost) VALUES ('', ' ').

Comment: `'$bill_cost '` should be `'$bill_cost'`

Comment: for some reason it only works when I put the keyword new mysqli( connection stuff here)

Answer (score 0):

Your `$_POST` values are empty because your form method is not set to POST, use

```
<form action="updatebill.php" method="post">
```

Comment: I strongly advise to use @utility s code to insert the values. Before, make sure the form is in fact submitted, with the code you have posted above your `$_POST` variables will be empty if the form hasn't been submitted. Check if the form has been submitted and all values are in fact not empty, then do the insert.